# Ways to speedup solution time for a large LP (>10 million decision variables)

Tags: performance, large-data, cplex, quantum-computing

I have a large LP with more than `10 million` decision variables and nearly the same number of constraints. I use `CPLEX` to solve the LP but it takes `~20 hours` to solve, and that's on the best server of our institution.

Are there ways to significantly speedup the solution time (without adding more servers)?

I've read about Quantum Computing and its application in optimization problems speedup. Does anybody have a similar experience in that, or more generally any other ways of reducing the solution time?

Comment: What is the type of your problem? May you can do cutting-plane methods to reduce the variables in your problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method or apply some heuristics.

Comment: It's a linear optimization (no MIP), with roughly 10 million decision variables and around the same number of constraints.

Comment: You can try to reduce your number of variables using some reduction techniques, like the `cutting plane method` as mentioned above. Also, you can see about heuristics, like `lagrangean relaxation`, `branch and bound`, `column generation`, etc. It depends on your problem type.

Answer (score 1):

if your model is a LP then I suggest [CPLEX Performance Tuning for Linear Programs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cplex-performance-tuning-linear-programs)

You could also try [data check 2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DataCheck.html) to see whether you have some numerical issues in your model.

If still no improvement you could try to improve your model.

NB:

If it s a MIP then you could read [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cplex-performance-tuning-mixed-integer-programs)